# How do I use an `onRequest` Firebase Function from the Emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I have a firebase function that is fired as a `return_url` from an external api... use goes to the external site, does stuff, and then a `return_url` is used to send data back to my app.

It is a Firebase Function `onRequest`. The deployed url to the function is something like `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/<function name>`

- What url would I use for the same function when I'm using the local emulators and how would I find that on my own?
- Where's the documentation for Firebase Functions ***with the Emulator***?

Comment: Some services offer testing tools e.g. Stripe CLI can trigger test webhooks for localhost. Or [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/) is pretty useful too.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [official Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#trigger_a_function_with_an_http_request):

> Used as arguments for `onRequest()`, the [Request](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) object gives you access to the properties of the HTTP request.

And from the [official documentation for the Cloud Functions emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator):

> The Firebase CLI includes a Cloud Functions emulator which can emulate the following function types:
>
> - HTTPS functions

Therefore, `onRequest` event is supported and should be used as normal for both the code deployed to Firebase and the code running in the local emulator.

Also, the documentation shows how the local URL is formed as follows:

`https://localhost:5001/my-project/us-central1/helloWorld`

> #### [Instrument your app for HTTPS functions emulation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#instrument_your_app_for_https_functions_emulation)
>
> Each HTTPS function in your code will be served from the local emulator using the following URL format:
>
> `http://$HOST:$PORT/$PROJECT/$REGION/$NAME`
>
> For example, a simple  `helloWorld`  function with the default host port and region would be served at:
>
> `https://localhost:5001/my-project/us-central1/helloWorld`

Also, as shown in [this tutorial](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-functions/test-firebase-authentication-cloud-functions-trigger-on-local-machine-with-emulators/#test-on-local-machine-with-emulators), when you start the emulator, in the CLI you can view the local URL for each emulator (Firestore, functions, etc.) and its UI if it applies.

---

```
...
✔  functions[helloWorld]: http function initialized 
(http://localhost:5001/my-project/us-central1/helloWorld).

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4001                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4001/functions │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at localhost:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
...
```